# Method for preventing passing temporaries as const reference that scales better then deleting the r-value overload

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference

When one wants to prevent someone passing a temporary as const reference one can delete the r-value overload:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo(const Bar& bar) : mBar(&bar) {} 
    Foo(const Bar&&) = delete;

private:

    const Bar* mBar;
};
```

However, when there's multiple such parameters this method does not scale well. It requires deleting every possible combination to be effective:

```
Foo(const Bar&&, const Baz&, const Qux&) = delete;
Foo(const Bar&, const Baz&&, const Qux&) = delete; 
Foo(const Bar&, const Baz&, const Qux&&) = delete;
Foo(const Bar&&, const Baz&&, const Qux&) = delete;
//And every other combination...
```

Are there methods that scale better then this?

Comment: Are you able to make the caller send a pointer, or maybe make them use `std::cref`?

Comment: Personally I would not prevent rvalues, since there are valid use case to pass a temporary there

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Such as? I'm storing const pointers to the parameters for later use as per the example given. If one passes in temporaries that surely cannot end well ?

Comment: `call_with_foo(Foo{get_temporary()})` is one example. The temporary lives as long as the foo, which is temporary too.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I see what you mean but the real `Foo` isn't something that is meant to be used in such a short-lived way.

Comment: @Unimportant and take note that deleting overloads that takes temporaries will not prevent all temporaries. Think about `Foo{std::min(bar1, Bar{})}`. Depending on the value of `bar1`, you'll get undefined behaviour anyways, since `std::min` will return `const T&` even if there is temporaries sent to it for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?  It makes it very clear that you don't want an rvalue, as well.

```
struct Foo{};
template <typename T>
struct NoRvalue {
    T t;
    NoRvalue(T & t);
    NoRvalue(T&& t) = delete;
};

void call_me(NoRvalue<Foo> a, NoRvalue<Foo> b);
void call_me2(Foo const & a, Foo const & b);

int main() {
    Foo f;
    call_me2(f, Foo());
    call_me(f, Foo()); // fails
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/z/LT9iSw